# storing array content into dictionary with keys properly

Tags: ios, json, nsarray

I have this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ios.com/ios/responseScript.php"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:&error];
NSMutableArray *someArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"Array Retrieved: %@", someArray);
```

It clearly gets json data from site. The PHP array is created like this:

```
$simpleProduct = array("John"=>"Employee","Jane"=>"Student","Jhonson"=>"Somejob","Mike"=>"Nothing");
echo json_encode($simpleProduct);
```

and when the result of objective-c code above is printed, it shows like:

> 2013-02-05 19:17:37.910 testProducts[26786:c07] Array Retrieved: {
>       Jane = Student;
>       Jhonson = Somejob;
>       John = Employee;
>       Mike = Nothing; }

Now I wish to have this data inserted into dictionary (NSMutableDictionary) so that for e.g. Jane is key and Student is value. So on for all other pairs.

How can this be done?

I am new to iOS development :)

Comment: Try this NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not you just get the results like this

```
NSDictionary *someDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

it makes your life easier, and after just access the values via keys like this

```
NSString *jane= [someDictionary objectForKey:@"Jane"];
```

Comment: holy code! that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you :) I guess at the beginning I just confuse myself by NSMutableArray